# Hash to Active Model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization, hash, active-model-serializers

I have a hash @branches that is basically:

```
{1 => 5}, {2 => 6}
```

Is it possible for me to send this to a serializer and get output json like so:

```
{ branch_id: 1, branch_name: 'Hello', count_5}
```

I've made a custom serializer and calling it like so:

```
render json: @branches, serializer: AvilableStockBranchSerializer
```

How can I pass the hash data to the serializer?

Comment: This question makes very little sense, first of all your input does not look like a hash at all - but rather an array of hashes. Second of all how is your serializer supposed to to know that `1 =  branch_id`? If you for whatever reason need your controller to accept a bunch of funky legacy params you should handle that with an params adapter - not in the serialization layer.

Comment: Your serializers should basically take a model and produce JSON. If you want to serialize an arbitrary hash than you're doing it wrong. Thats not what AMS is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need AMS?

You can use `@branches`.to_json instead

Comment: To exclude fields you don't want to be returned on the public API.